# TFS 2013 On-Premises Sprint Board Statuses Customization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

In TFS 2013 Web Access when I go to Sprint Board I see only 2 States Active and Closed.

I wanted to add few more statuses like In Progress and Blocked. I downloaded the process Template using the Process editor that is part of TFS Power Tools.

When I looked at the Process Template workflow there is already To do, In Progress, Done and Removed as shown in the figure attached..

But these are not showing up in the Task Work Item. All I see in state dropdown is Active and Closed. 
    How do I change it so that I see Active, In-Progress, Completed and Blocked States.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, States on the Sprint board are To Do, In Progress, and Done (assume you're working with scrum project template).

In order to add another state on the Sprint board, you need to:

1. Run the WITAdmin.exe exportcommonprocessconfig command to export the 
   common process config from your TFS project.
2. Customize the file to be similar to the followings:

```html
<TaskWorkItems category=”Microsoft.TaskCategory”>

   <States>
     <!-->States you want to have<-->
   </States>
</TaskWorkItems>
```

3. Run the WITAdmin.exe importcommonprocessconfig command to import the customized Common Process Config file back to TFS project.

Please check this blog for the detailed information on how to get it work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/01/19/adding-additional-states-onto-the-agile-task-board-in-tfs2012.aspx

Be note that: states on the Sprint board should be the same as the States defined in the WIT.